# Is Machine Reading Comprehension (MRC) outdated?

Tags: machine-learning, language-model

I recently went through some litterature about knowledge-enhanced language models and found connections with the Machine Reading Comprehension (MRC) task. However, I couldn't find papers more recent than 2020 on this topic. Therefore, I wonder whether this task is now outdated and if so, is there a known reason for that like it has been replaced by a more adapted task?

Answer (score 1):

Checking on [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/task/machine-reading-comprehension/latest#papers-list), we can see that there are 27 papers on Machine Reading Comprehension published only in 2023, with the latest released on November, so I would say that it is not outdated by any means.

Comment: @BarbaraGendron was the answer helpful?